# Add values from Table1 into Table2 without adding duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

[MySQL 5.5]

I have two tables - `Table_1` and `Table_2`.

They have identical columns - `Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4`.

`Table_1` can have duplicates on columns `Col1` and `Col2`.

Example-1:

```
   Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
1) a   ,b   ,c   ,1      
2) a   ,b   ,d   ,2
```

Now Table_2 has the following rows:

Example-2:

```
   Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
1) a   ,b   ,e   ,1      
2) a   ,c   ,f   ,2
```

I want to write all rows from `Table_2` into `Table_1` that do not have duplicates on `Col1` and `Col2`. In the above instance, the insert should ignore row 1 in Example-2 above and add row 2 since there are no duplicates for combination (a,c) in `Table_1`.

Adding Unique keys on `Col1` and `Col2` will not work as it will delete row no 2 in Example 1.

Both `Table_1` and `Table_2` have 2 million rows each. Nested `select` statements(which I tried) have spelled disaster in terms of execution time.

Is there another way out of this?

Comment: So, which one is it, MySQL or SQL Server (and please add the version too)

Comment: MySQL 5.5. Edited my question to reflect changes.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
INSERT INTO Table_1
SELECT *
FROM Table_2 A
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table_1
                 WHERE Col1 = A.Col1
                 AND Col2 = A.Col2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into table1
select *
from table2
where concat(Col1,Col2) not in
(
    select concat(col1,col2)
    from table1
) as T
```

Comment: This isn't right, what happens if the values for `Col1` and `Col2` in `Table_1` are `a, bc` and for `Table_2` they are `ab, c`?

Comment: In that case, this does not work... but it gives you the basic structure of the answer. Frankly, Lamak's solution should work fine, so why not go with that?

Comment: or you can still use this one just use change all the concat to `CONCAT(col1,"'",col2)`

Answer (score 0):

See below. Its using join so will have better performance.

```
INSERT INTO Table_1
SELECT T2.Col1
    ,T2.Col2 
    ,T2.Col3
    ,T2.Col4
FROM Table_2 T2
LEFT JOIN Table_1 T1
    ON T2.Col1 = T1.Col1
    AND T2.Col2 = T1.Col2
WHERE T1.Col1 IS NULL
    AND T1.Col2 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the rows that don't exist via LEFT JOIN and NULL checking in the WHERE clause

```
INSERT INTO Table_1 (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)
SELECT Table_2.Col1, Table_2.Col2, Table_2.Col3, Table_2.Col4
FROM Table_2
LEFT JOIN Table_1
  ON Table_2.Col1 = Table_1.Col1
    AND Table_2.Col2 = Table_1.Col2
WHERE Table_2.Col1 IS NULL;
```